# ModuleNotFoundError even after I do pip install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

Importing these packages:

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from datacleaner import autoclean
```

Getting the errors:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 import numpy as np
----> 4 #import seaborn as sns
----> 5 from datacleaner import autoclean
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seaborn'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'datacleaner'
```

I did `pip install seaborn` and `pip install datacleaner` in my terminal but it still has this error. I'm using Jupyter Notebook.